# Why argv[-1] shows the manual title in fish_title?

Tags: fish

I'm customising the title shows in the terminal windows by defining the `fish_title` function. I want to show `X` after I execute `man X` and I thought `eval $argv[-1]` would give me that, but it gives me the man title itself (e.g. `FISH(1) fish-shell`). Why?

I'm getting the actual argument with `(string split " " $argv)[-1]`, but I would like to know why the former attempt gives me that unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm customising the title shows in the terminal windows by defining the fish_terminal function.

You mean the fish_title function.

> ```
> eval $argv[-1]
> ```

This takes the last argument and executes it as a command. The argument `fish_title` receives is the current commandline. The command you are executing is `man X`. So it executes man again.

Because multi-line titles aren't commonly supported, fish will only use the first line of `fish_title`s output as the title. That's the title line of the man page.

---

`eval` is absolutely the entire wrong thing here.

You mean to use `echo`. Just simply `echo $argv[-1]` to give the entire commandline, or `echo (string split " " $argv)[-1]` to give the last word of the commandline.

Not that I'd assume it's all that useful - e.g. if you do `git diff something.cpp` it would print `something.cpp`, but you do you.

Comment: Yes, I mean `fish_title`  Thanks for your answer. On more question though: the reason I tried `eval` is that, as you pointed out, `echo $argv[-1]` returns the entire command, not only the argument passed, but I expected `X` because the documentation says it is a list and gives examples as `ls -l $argv` for a function called `ll`. I would expect `ll` is not part of `$argv`, right?

Comment: Where in the documentation? The only part I can find is about function definition.

Comment: In this case the function `fish_title` is called like `fish_title 'man X'`, so $argv consists of one element - `man X`. This has nothing to do with `ls -l $argv` being called, and nothing to do with what eval does, because eval *executes*. It's wrong anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking about `man x`, so I expected `$argv[-1]` to return only `x`. I never considered `fish_title` as the actual command. Thanks for all